# Hibernate doesn't save child with assigned ID

Tags: hibernate

I have two entity Parent and Child. Parent can have only one child.
When I am saving the parent, I get a CONSTRAINT VIOLATION exception.

So, why Hibernate doesn't save the child before saving parent entity?

Java code used to save a parent:

```
Child c = new Child();
c.setId(1);

Parent p = new Parent();
p.setId(4);
p.setChild(c);
```

parent-hbm.xml file:

```
<hibernate-mapping default-cascade="all">
    <class name="com.ParentImpl" table="Parent" dynamic-insert="false" dynamic-update="false">
        <cache usage="read-write" />
        <id name="id" type="java.lang.Long" unsaved-value="null">
            <column name="ID" sql-type="BIGINT"/>
        </id>
        <many-to-one name="child" class="com.ChildImpl" foreign-key="CHILDFKC" cascade="all" lazy="false" fetch="select">
            <column name="CHILD_FK" not-null="true" sql-type="BIGINT" unique="true"/>
        </many-to-one>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

child-hbm-.xml

```
<hibernate-mapping default-cascade="all">
    <class name="ChildImpl" table="DATA_DELETION_PERIODS" dynamic-insert="true" dynamic-update="true">
        <cache usage="read-write" />
        <id name="id" type="java.lang.Long" unsaved-value="null">
            <column name="ID" sql-type="BIGINT"/>
        </id>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To properly answer you question, you really need to provide the Child.hbm.xml file at a minimum. Without this additional information, this answer is at best a guess . . .

Does your Child.hbm.xml file have the same hibernate configuration for its id as Parent.hbm.xml - with an unsaved-value of "null"?

```
<hibernate-mapping default-cascade="all">
  <class name="com.ChildImpl" table="Child" dynamic-insert="false" dynamic-update="false">
    <id name="id" type="java.lang.Long" unsaved-value="null">
      <column name="ID" sql-type="BIGINT"/>
    </id>
    ....
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

If so, that is your problem. Setting the id of the child in your code that creates the parent/child tells Hibernate that this entity is already persistent (since it has a non-null id), so it doesn't try to insert it.

Hope this helps.

Sarah